# Why flash message won't appear if I use CanCan with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

Assuming that I'm not signed in.
In this case, it displays this flash notice when accessing to actions in mails_controller.

```
You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

However, it won't display in communities_controller.
Why? and How can I fix?

**mails_controller.rb**

```
class MailsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    ....
end
```

**communities_controller.rb**

```
class CommunitiesController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource :find_by => :id
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try moving the `load_and_authorize_resource` line after the `before_filter`. The `load_and_authorize_resource` line will raise an exception when it can't find the resource for member actions which may be happening before you even get to the `before_filter` line